# Make Spring replace placeholders in different file type (other than Spring's configs)

Tags: java, spring, properties, placeholder

Is there a way to make spring (v.3.0) parse placeholders in files that are not `.properties`?
I know I can write my own `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` but I was looking for a "cleaner" way to do it.

**EDIT:**

To be more specific, what I actually want to do is to replace placeholders present in `.sql` files. So the values of the placeholders are stored in `.properties` but the placeholders are used in `.sql` files.

Comment: What would you consider "cleaner" than PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer?

Comment: @GaryF - I think @Drahakar is referring to the fact that PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer only works on bean definitions, so to use it he'd need to embed his SQL in to bean definition files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` bean will replace placeholders in other bean definitions.  Specifically, it updates the values of bean properties in bean definitions ... before the beans are actually created.  Therefore, if you wanted to use `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` to modify SQL, that SQL would need to be embedded in bean property values.  This class cannot replace properties in arbitrary files.

If you want to replace placeholders in arbitrary files, the [`PropertyPlaceholderHelper`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/PropertyPlaceholderHelper.html) class is a better bet.  For example, the method

```
String replacePlaceholders(String value, Properties properties)
```

will replace placeholders in `value` with properties taken from `properties` returning the rewritten string.  You could easily adapt / wrap this to replace placeholders in a file.

Answer (score 2):

`PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` can be supplied with an arbitrary `Properties` object (via `properties` property).

Comment: +1, and then you can use, say, commons-configuration to load whatever format you want.

Comment: +1 - I've been (ab-)using PPCs for months, and I hadn't noticed this feature.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you use maven, but if you do, I'd use [resource filtering](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html) to inject the properties into the sql files at deploy time (there are similar solutions for ant, also) and let Spring's `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` use the same property files at run time. That way everything is where it belongs (after all, the best place for properties is a .properties file).

Comment: that's not deploy time.  That's WAR-file-build time.

Comment: true. I guess I meant deploy in the sense of executing `mvn deploy`